# Set User Pool 'App Client Id' as audience for HTTP API AWS YAML - token does not have a valid audience

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, serverless, aws-sam

How do you resolve `token does not have a valid audience` by adding the correct audience to the aws authorizers?

The following snippet from the `yaml` config will return `token does not have a valid audience` once I use the `Authorization` header with a valid JWT

```
Auth:
  DefaultAuthorizer: JwtAuthentication
  Authorizers:
    JwtAuthentication:
      IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
      JwtConfiguration:
        audience:
          - my-audience
        issuer: !Sub https://cognito-idp.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${OperationsUserPool}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I decoded the JWT generated from my lambda

```
const login = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider
        .adminInitiateAuth(params)
        .promise();
```

I noticed that the `audience` was the `App Client Id` but wasn't sure how to obtain that `audience` so it turns out it's the `Ref` for your `AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient`

You can find more info here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpoolclient.html#cfn-cognito-userpoolclient-allowedoauthflowsuserpoolclient

```
Auth:
  DefaultAuthorizer: JwtAuthentication
  Authorizers:
    JwtAuthentication:
      IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
      JwtConfiguration:
        audience:
          - !Ref OperationsUserPoolClient
        issuer: !Sub https://cognito-idp.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${OperationsUserPool}
```

Hope this helps someone!